# Wordpress: Make Text max-width:660px an images max-width:1000px

Tags: image, wordpress, css

I would like to have in Wordpress the normal text width 660px and the images between text wider than the text (max-width:1000px).

How can i handle that?

Answer (score 0):

You could give images negative left and right margins. In order to work, though, they shouldn't be `max-width`, but just `width`:

```
 .container {
    width: 660px;
}

img {
    width: 1000px;
    margin-left: -170px;
    margin-right: -170px;
}
```

Another alternative, use a grid system and great a new `.row` or whatever your grid system calls it for each image, with columns that are wider than the one used for the text.